# MySQL error getting total values between two dates and another filter

Tags: mysql, sum, between

I want to get SUM values from a table between two dates but I have another filter also. I am getting syntax error and could not find what is wrong. This is the SQL sentence:

```
SUM(IF((date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59') AND ql=1),total,0) AS t1q1,
SUM(IF((date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59') AND ql=2),total,0) AS t1q2,
SUM(IF((date BETWEEN '2019-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59') AND ql=1),total,0) AS t2q1,
SUM(IF((date BETWEEN '2019-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59') AND ql=2),total,0) AS t2k2
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY productID
ORDER BY productID ASC
```

Comment: `SUM(case when date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59'  AND ql=1 then total else 0 end) AS t1q1,`

Comment: if you get an error share the excact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
SUM(case when date>='2020-01-01' and date<'2020-02-01' AND ql=1 then total else 0 end) t1q1,
SUM(case when date>='2020-01-01' and date<'2020-02-01' AND ql=2 then total else 0 end) t1q2,
SUM(case when date>='2019-12-01' and date<'2020-01-01' AND ql=1 then total else 0 end) t2q1,
SUM(case when date>='2019-12-01' and date<'2020-01-01' AND ql=2 then total else 0 end) t2q2
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY productID
ORDER BY productID ASC
```

Comment: `else 0 ` is excess - SUM() ignores NULL values. And the conditions by `date` may be moved to WHERE.

Comment: I know, but I find using `else` better readable for newbies to SQL. Otherwise it is harder to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Akina: And the condition by date can NOT be moved to WHERE

Comment: Oops.. I have mislooked that the month differs.